# visual studio giving --alowjs is not set when trying to import ts file with same name as js file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I have a angular2 app written in typescript and when I try to run it in visual studio I get the error

```
Build:Module '../../services/company.service' was resolved to '<filepath>/company.service.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
```

the line the error is occurring on looks like this:

```
import { CompanyService } from '../../services/company.service';
```

I have a ts file with the same name as the compiled js file, how do I get vs to resolve the imported file as a ts file instead of a js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, this happened after I had rebuilt the project on "Release" so it was resolving the ts files to the release js files, I just moved the release folder so it wasn't in the projects directory anymore and it worked.